# Помогите создать функцию которая считает среднюю оценку из массива в JS

Tags: javascript

Не получается сделать функцию которая считает среднюю оценку из массива. Попытался сделать это через разные методы, но к сожалению почему-то не выходит.

Задача такова: Создать функцию которая считает среднюю оценку и выводит имя и среднюю оценку для каждого элемента массива.

Вот массив:

```
let studentList= [
    {name: "Ivan", marks: [8,7,6,5,8]},
    {name: "Adrian", marks: [9,8,8,7,8]},
    {name: "Andrei", marks: [6,8,9,7,7]},
    {name: "Alex", marks: [10,9,9,8,10]},
    {name: "Maxim", marks: [4,5,7,7,6]}
]
```

Вот что получилось у меня:

```
let marksSum = 0;
let length = studentList.length;
var result = studentList.reduce(function(marksSum, current){
    return marksSum + current;
});
console.log(result/length);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let studentList = [
    {name: "Ivan", marks: [8,7,6,5,8]},
    {name: "Adrian", marks: [9,8,8,7,8]},
    {name: "Andrei", marks: [6,8,9,7,7]},
    {name: "Alex", marks: [10,9,9,8,10]},
    {name: "Maxim", marks: [4,5,7,7,6]}
];

let averages = studentList.map(s => {
  return {
    name: s.name,
    av: s.marks.reduce((a, i) => a + i) / s.marks.length
  };
});
console.log(averages);
```

Comment: Спасибо, не думал что это будет прямо так просто

Comment: @Velk Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: @Igor, а в целом, правильнее было бы использовать Object.assign, дабы каждый раз не дописывать поля? Так сказать с заделом на будущее.

Comment: @OliverPatterson Возможно. Я руководствовался этим - "выводит имя и среднюю оценку для каждого".